References in complex manifolds
We say a holomorphic manifold is a smooth manifold, locally modelled on $\mathbb C^n$, and whose transition functions are holomorphic. For example, the complex sphere $\mathbb S_{\mathbb C}^ 4 = \{ z \in \mathbb C^5 \mid z_1^2 +z_2^2 +z_3^2 +z_4^2 +z_5^2 = 1\}$ is a holomorphic Riemannian manifold.  So, it is an complex version of  Riemannian manifold.
I have read about geometry of submanifolds (shape operator, first & second fundamental form, Gauss-codazzi equation etc) in Riemannian   geometry. Is there any analogue the above said notions (i.e. notions of immersions of surfaces) in complex (Riemannian) manifolds?

A nice paper that studies subvarieties of complex projective space using local differential geometry is one by Griffiths and Harris. http://www.numdam.org/item/ASENS_1979_4_12_3_355_0/

You do not want to keep saying complex (or holomorphic) Riemannian manifolds. The appropriate notion for a metric structure will be a Hermitian manifold.
